# How to access column data from a table in python?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to get column data from a table with multiple columns for generating some reports.

I tried writing a function to access column data:

```
def get_data_from_column(status, "something_am_missing"):
    report_data = ReportRepository.get(status.id)
    return report_data.get(ReportRepository)
```

I want to access data from each column from table `report`.

```
class Status(db.Model, BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "status"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) #automagically becomes an auto increment
    audience = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
    target = db.Column(db.String())
    report_path = db.Column(db.String())
    status = db.Column(db.String())
    score_column = db.Column(db.String())
    target_column = db.Column(db.String())
    update_time = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, server_default=func.now())
    product = db.Column(db.String())
    product_run_id = db.Column(db.String())
    command_id = db.Column(db.String())

    report = relationship("Report", back_populates="status")


    def __init__(self, audience, target, report_path, status, score_column, target_column, update_time, product, product_run_id, id_space, seed_file, background_file, evaluation_type, cluster, qubole_token, command_id):
        self.audience = audience
        self.target = target
        self.report_path = report_path
        self.status = status
        self.score_column = score_column
        self.target_column = target_column
        self.update_time = update_time
        self.product = product
        self.product_run_id = product_run_id

    def succeeded(self):
        return self.status == StatusStates.SUCCESS

class Report(db.Model, BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "report"

    report_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Status.id),primary_key = True)
    gains_data = db.Column(db.TEXT())
    score_histogram_data = db.Column(db.TEXT())
    descriptors_data = db.Column(db.TEXT())
    baselines_data = db.Column(db.TEXT())
    county_data = db.Column(db.TEXT())
    state_data = db.Column(db.TEXT())
    features_data = db.Column(db.TEXT())

    status = relationship("Status", back_populates="report")


    def __init__(self, gains_data, score_histogram_data, descriptors_data, baselines_data, county_data, state_data,features_data):
        self.gains_data = gains_data
        self.score_histogram_data = score_histogram_data
        self.descriptors_data = descriptors_data
        self.baselines_data = baselines_data
        self.county_data = county_data
        self.state_data = state_data
        self.features_data = features_data

    def succeeded(self):
        return self.report == StatusStates.SUCCESS
```

The below class is the one I have declared for various methods.

```
class ReportRepository:
    @staticmethod
    def get(report_id):
        return Report.query.filter_by(id=report_id).one()
```

I am not able to write a function that would extract data from each column?

Comment: That's a lot of code. How about, input, expected output, minimal reproducible code with imports?

Comment: This is my table with Class Report and table name "report" I want to access data from each column for this table for records in class Status and table "status".
Can you ignore the above part and then see it.